# In Swift 3, why is the void return value of functions, -> (), only sometimes inferred, but other times, must be declared?

Tags: swift3, syntax, closures, declaration, void

Consider the following code:

```
typealias bar = ()->()

let foo:bar = { baz -> () in
    print("foobar")
    return ()
}

let baz = foo()

print("\(baz)")
```

Which outputs:

> foobar
>
> ()

Now, if we change this line:

```
let foo:bar = { baz -> () in
```

to this:

```
let foo:bar = { baz in
```

... then nothing happens. I.e., `-> ()` gets inferred by the compiler. (Note: the compiler is happy also if we omit `return ()`.)

However, meanwhile, if we change this line:

```
typealias bar = ()->()
```

to this:

```
typealias bar = ()
```

... then the compiler freaks out and commits suicide. Why?

This seems in conflict with Swift's documentation, which defines `()` (aka `Void`) as:

> The return type of functions that don’t explicitly specify a return type

According to that statement, since `typealias bar = ()->()` explicitly specifies a return type, therefore by definition, it cannot return `()`—and yet it does! This is completely illogical and self-contradictory.

Would someone kindly please explain to me what they are thinking with this? What is the rationale here?

If `->()` is supposed to always be inferred then why even have it? Why not just say that `()` is always a function, such that `()()` always returns `()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is the case you're talking about:

```
typealias bar = ()

let foo: bar = { baz -> () in
    print("foobar")
    return ()
}
```

The right hand of an assignment is a closure of type `() -> ()`, which is unevaluated. `foo` is expected to have type bar (`()`), but that would only be the case if the closure was evaluated, e.g.:

```
let foo: bar = { baz -> () in
    print("foobar")
    return ()
}()
```

Comment: Yes but according to the definition of `()`, `()` and `()->()` should be equivalent in meaning, since `()` is the type returned by functions that do not specify a return type. However, to declare a typealias for a function you must always specify a return type, from what I can tell, so perhaps their documentation is just poorly worded.

Comment: `However, to declare a typealias for a function you must always specify a return type, from what I can tell.` correct.

Comment: `() and ()->() should be equivalent in meaning` they are not. There's a key part in that definition that you quoted, that I think you missed: void is the ***return*** type of functions that don’t explicitly specify a return type

Comment: @CommaToast It's not the type of the whole function, but merely the type of the return.

Comment: I guess the documentation is correct considering that the right-hand-side of a typealias declaration is not itself a function whose value has no type (if it's a function, then its value is a type—whereas a void value is a value of type void, i.e. a typeless value).

Comment: `Void`/`()` isn't typeless, `Void` is a type, and the only instance of that type is `Void`

Comment: Right. That's where it was confusing me.  I.e, in `typealias bar = ()`, the RHS returns a value `()` of type Type to the LHS. Whereas in `typealias bar = ()->()`, RHS returns a value `()->()` of type Type to the LHS. Since in this sense, `()->()` is a Type and not a Function, therefore `->()` does not get inferred. Got it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149847/discussion-between-alexander-and-commatoast).

Answer (score 1):

I like [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45246553/957768), but here's another angle that might prove helpful.

With a `typealias bar = ...` declaration, you're defining a type. That definition needs to be complete and unambiguous. Otherwise, the type system won't be able to check whether things you declare later are members of the type. This declaration provides the complete signature of the type -- for function/closure types, that means its set of parameter types and its return type, even if both are `Void` (aka `()`).

With a `let foo: bar = ...` you're declaring a value and claiming that it must be a member of the type. Because parts of the type's definition are already known (thanks to the typealias), you don't need to repeat them when you declare a member of the type:

- Your closure doesn't need to declare its return type because that's part of the function type your closure conforms to. You can `return` any value of the expected type within your closure. (Or, since your function type defines a return type of `Void`, you can`return` nothing.)
- Your closure doesn't need to declare its parameters' types because the typealias already did that, too. (Or, since your sole parameter's type is `Void`, you don't need to declare parameters at all.)

Leaving off bits of the closure syntax when defining a closure whose type is known is one of Swift's *type inference* features. You can consider it equivalent to how, if you have an `enum Foo { case one, two, three }` and a `func bar(_ foo: Foo)`, you're allowed to pass just `.one` in a call (`bar(.one)`). `Foo.one` is the fully qualified name for that constant, but just `.one` suffices because Swift can infer the `Foo` type.